# Error in connecting with ms access database with password using VB6

Tags: vb6

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()

        Dim conString As String

            conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
                      & "Data Source=D:\Dheeraj\VB6_DH\db5.mdb" _
                      & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=dheeraj;" _

                     '& "App.Path & Persist Security Info=False;"
            Set CON = New ADODB.Connection
            With CON
                .ConnectionString = conString
                .Open
            End With

    End Sub
```

Hi,
here is the code to connect ms access database with password protection. However it is giving an error 'Could not use ";file already in use' can you please tell me what could be the issue.

Comment: Maybe the database is damaged. Compact and repair from Access and try again. Also try opening it with MS Access first and see if it works.

Comment: please change  `Password=dheeraj;`  this with  `;Password:dheeraj;`

Comment: with '& "Jet OLEDB:Database Password = dheeraj;"' error is 'Could not find installable ISAM' and with the modification suggested by Sujith error remains same as i mentioned. MicSim, database is opening normally with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this.
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Masterfile.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxx;"

Answer (score 0):

Missing `;` between *.mdb* and *Jet*

```
conString =  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
          & ";Data Source=D:\Dheeraj\VB6_DH\db5.mdb" _
          & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=dheeraj;"
```

Comment: Thanx, however it still gives error 'Invalid Argument' at .Open.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a connection string I just pulled from on of my (working) project:
>
> "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';Data Source='%path%\%file%'; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=%pwd%;"
>
> So I guess the database source should be enclosed in a pair of single-quotes.

**EDIT**: Cross that, it shouldn't make any difference (as with the single quotes around the provider name). I never read your question until the end.

Close any programs currently having the database open and then delete any ***.ldb** file left in the same directory as the database. If you cannot delete the ***.ldb** file, then it means there's still a process running that has that file open. Hunt it down and kill it, then retry deleting the file.

Comment: I have stored database in the same file and folder as vb6 project. There it doesn't show any .ldb files. Where should I find them otherwise. I tried with different VB6 program and new database with password, there it's working perfectly fine with no issues, i don't know what is the issue with form and project I am working on.

Comment: Is the file on a server or a folder with special permissions? If so, check if the following applies: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289681

Comment: No there were no special permissions for the folder. However what i did is i created new database and new vb6 project and stored the database in the same folder as vb6 project. Here it is working perfectly fine with no special arrangements. Now it is working perfectly fine. I couldn't get what was the issue with earlier settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two `;` before `Jet OLEDB`

And try this code for connection

```
Public Con as New ADODB.Connection

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim conString As String

     conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
          & "Data Source=D:\Dheeraj\VB6_DH\db5.mdb" _
          & ";;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=dheeraj;"

     Con.Open conString
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks salih, its also not working. I tried with new database too but still giving an error. I tried with different VB6 program and new database with password, there it's working perfectly fine with no issues, i don't know what is the issue with form and project I am working on.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
Dim DatabasePath As String
Dim DatabasePassword As String

DatabasePath = App.Path & "\Storage.mdb"
DatabasePassword = "mypc"

Set Con = New ADODB.Connection

With Con
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password='';" & _
                        "User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & DatabasePath & ";" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Database Password='" & DatabasePassword & "'"
    .Open
End With
```